# run hadoop nutch on oozie gets old racing condition

Tags: hadoop, nutch, oozie

I can run hadoop jar apache-nutch-1.7.job org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl args in command line just fine, but when run in oozie, I get an exception

org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://server:8020/user/hdfs/.staging/job_1416525929767_0494/job.splitmetainfo
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl$InitTransition.createSplits(JobImpl.java:1566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl$InitTransition.transition(JobImpl.java:1430)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl$InitTransition.transition(JobImpl.java:1388)

an old Jira reported this exception

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-5471

but it was supposely fixed back in version 2.1.1-beta. I am on yarn 2.5.0.

Any one else see this?

Comment: Hi, 
I am facing the same issue. Could you solve this problem ?

Comment: Hi, +1, running Camus on CDH5 and YARN. Looks like its related to some YARN specialities?

Comment: I never got past this. Drop oozie in favor of Rundeck because of this one bug.